# Redirect from an action with onstart attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I noticed that since I defined an onstart behavior  in my button, navigation rules are ignoring me.
My button:

```
<p:commandButton
    id="btnSend"
    value="#{txt['button.send']}" process="@form"
    immediate="true"
    action="#{controller.goToSend}"
    onstart="generate();">
</p:commandButton>
```

and my faces-config:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{controller.goToSend}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/private/menu/lists/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect include-view-params="true">
            <view-param>
                <name>back</name>
                <value>1</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>  
</navigation-rule>
```

If I remove the onstart attribute it works.

What do you think?

Comment: Two things: 1) `<p:commandButton>` fires an ajax request by default, and you should avoid redirection from ajax. 2) Why are you still using navigation rules for this?

Comment: Are you implying that `onstart` function didn't cause a JavaScript error?

Comment: @Luiggi Finally, avoiding ajax redirection it's working, so thank you very much.

Comment: But with ajax="false", onstart is ignored, that is not the solution. I check that my problem is occurring when I debug with a breakpoint in goToSend method. Without breakpoints everything is ok. It must be something about redirection timing...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, why should you avoid redirection from ajax?